# Wordpress: How to serve the same content with a different template based on URL

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

Long short of it is this: if you go to mysite.com/blog, you see the blog landing page, which uses the index.php template in my theme. However, I want to be able to go to mysite.com/blog-content and get all the same content, but using my page-blog-content.php template in my theme.

How can this be done?

Thanks in advance!

*** EDIT ***

To clarify, I'm trying to have two different URLs, /blog and /blog-content load *the same content*; specifically, the blog landing page. The only difference between those two URLs should be the template they use. I have two templates in my theme ready to go, I just need to make /blog-content mirror /blog and direct it to use my page-blog-content.php template.

Comment: If there's no pagination involved, maybe a Shortcode could solve this...

Comment: Were you able to find a solution for this? If so, can you provide an example?

Answer (score 2):

There's heaps of options available, but (I think?) your question is too broad to answer specifically.

In general, you can select a specific template for a given page/post (from within the page/post edit screen).

Otherwise, you can create a specific template that is selected, based on its filename, for a certain slug, category, etc...

Refer here: [Wordpress Codex -> Template Hierarchy](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy)

Hope this helps!

Comment: I've already gotten that far, no worries. My actual blog page is exactly how I want it and my theme is complete. 

The specific issue I'm trying to solve is i want just the content (not headers or footers) for the blog landing page. So I created a second template called page-content.blog.php and I want to alternately load the blog landing page with that template instead of the regular one depending on my url (/blog or /blog-content). 

So, in short, same content, two templates, depending on URL. Looking at your link, it seems conditional tags might get me there. Is that best practice?

Comment: @JohnHutch Sorry for delay responding.  It looks like most of my answer is redundant since your clarification, sorry ;-)  I've worked with conditional tags before, but I'm not sure _how_ this could be used to achieve what you're after... What about creating a "dummy/stub" post for "/blog-content", that uses the same single template file as "/blog".  This template switches behaviour based on post name/id from conditional tags (and _explicitly_ resets its wp_query and then queries its content from "/blog" if its id is "/blog_content")?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [theme switching](http://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Switching) feature/plugins of wordpress. It works with URL's

Comment: I'm not actually looking to switch themes, though -- just the one template within the same theme I'm currently using. Furthermore, I'm still left with the issue of how to get another page (or, at least, another URL) to display the blog landing page content.

Comment: One way to do this is by editting the code in that page to look what parameters are passed and then define the [page template](http://codex.wordpress.org/Pages)

Comment: I'm not sure I follow: edit what code in which page to define which template?